# UWP can not x:bind data in ControlTemplate of MediaTransportControls

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am customizing the MediaTransportControls in UserControl.

But in ControlTemplate with TargetType="MediaTransportControls",

I can not x:bind or binding the data in code-behind.

At line **TextBlock Text="{x:Bind localTime, Mode=OneWay}"** , x:Bind localTime can not work. There is an error "The property 'localTime' was not found in type 'MediaTransportControls"

I think that x:bind only finds properties in MediaTransportControls.

How to x:bind find properties in my UserControl code-behind?

Here is my UserControl xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomMediaTransportControls" TargetType="MediaTransportControls">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MediaTransportControls">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind localTime, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid>
    <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="myMediaPlayerElement"
                        AutoPlay="False"
        <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
            <MediaTransportControls Style="{StaticResource CustomMediaTransportControls}"/>
        </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
    </MediaPlayerElement>
</Grid>
```

Here is my UserControl code-behind

```
public sealed partial class MainMedia : UserControl
{
    private string localTime = "My Local Time";

    public MainMedia()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use x:bind in `UserContro`l, but currently you need to modify a `ControlTemplate` in `UserControl` and bind it to codebehind. In my test, `DependencyProperty` can only be bound once. What is displayed in `MediaTransportControls` is only the default value of `DependencyProperty`, which cannot be changed, This behavior is similar to "mode=oneTime".

Here is a solution, add another `UserControl`(UserTextControl) to the `ControlTemplate` of `MediaTransportControls`, which can display the current time.

##### MyUserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomMediaTransportControls" TargetType="MediaTransportControls">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MediaTransportControls">
                    <StackPanel Background="White">
                        <local:UserTextControl/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid>
    <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="myMediaPlayerElement"
                    AutoPlay="True" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/sample-5s.mp4" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
        <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
              <MediaTransportControls Style="{StaticResource CustomMediaTransportControls}"/>
        </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
    </MediaPlayerElement>
</Grid>
```

##### UserTextControl.xaml

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind localTime,Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

##### UserTextControl.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class UserTextControl : UserControl
{
    DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public UserTextControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {

        GeographicRegion userRegion = new GeographicRegion();
        string regionCode = userRegion.CodeTwoLetter;

        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("year month day hour minute second", new[] { regionCode });
        localTime = timeFormatter.Format(DateTime.Now);

    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty localTimeProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("localTime", typeof(string), typeof(UserTextControl), new PropertyMetadata("UserTextControl default string"));
  

    public string localTime
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(localTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(localTimeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! , get locaTime indirectly via UserControl is a good idea.